# How to write an SQL query for this scenerio?

Tags: sql-server, matching, records

I'm trying to write a query where I want all the items in table1 that are in table2 which meets the first inner join criteria below (this is work find).

Then I want to check table3 to if there are exceptions.  Exceptions are base on reference numbers (REF_NO).  If the reference number exist in table3 then I need to check if the store number (STORE_NO) matches.  If they match  then I want the matching record from table1.  If not then exclude the matching record from table1.

However, if there reference number DOES NOT exist in table3 then I want the record from table1 that match with table2.

Thanks

```
USE master
GO

table1
table2
table3

SELECT
   T1.TERMINAL,
   T1.OPERATOR,
   T1.TRANS_NO,
   T1.SEQ_NO,
   T1.STORE_NO,
   T2.REF_NO,
   T2.SDATE,
   T2.EDATE,
   T1.POS_DATE,
   T1.ITEM,
   T1.ITYPE,
   T1.SOLD_QTY,
   T1.PRICE,
   T2.OI_AMT
FROM [table1] As T1

INNER JOIN [table2] As T2
ON (T1.ITEM = T2.ITEM)  And (T1.POS_DATE BETWEEN T2.SDATE And T2.EDATE)

INNER JOIN [table3] As T3
ON (T2.REF_NO = T3.REF_NO) And (T1.STORE_NO = T3.STORE)
```

Comment: How about a LEFT JOIN to table3? and then a where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
   T1.TERMINAL,
   T1.OPERATOR,
   T1.TRANS_NO,
   T1.SEQ_NO,
   T1.STORE_NO,
   T2.REF_NO,
   T2.SDATE,
   T2.EDATE,
   T1.POS_DATE,
   T1.ITEM,
   T1.ITYPE,
   T1.SOLD_QTY,
   T1.PRICE,
   T2.OI_AMT
FROM [table1] As T1
INNER JOIN [table2] As T2
    ON T1.ITEM = T2.ITEM
    AND T1.POS_DATE > T2.SDATE 
    AND T1.POS_DATE <= T2.EDATE
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT TOP (1) 1
                FROM table3 as T31
                WHERE T2.REF_NO = T31.REF_NO
                AND T1.STORE_NO = T31.STORE)
OR NOT EXISTS ( SELECT TOP (1) 1
                FROM table3 as T32
                WHERE T2.REF_NO = T32.REF_NO)
```

This should work, it checks both of your conditions. I also would encourage you not to use `BETWEEN` clause and specify date ranges using two conditions.

Comment: It might pick date range you don't need. Although it can happen rarely, but this is generally better practice